# What is "inline thread"?

Tags: java, multithreading

What does "inline thread" mean?

I got this question during my latest interview.  Anybody used this?

Comment: sounds like smoke and mirrors, I have never heard this term. However there is this answer http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_inline_thread_in_java .

Comment: Wow, that is the first time I've seen wikianswers provide a useful answer.

Comment: Guess I would fail this interview.  (Its a terrible question, because (a) this use of `inline` for creating objects is far from official or widespread, and (b) it has nothing to do with threads, and the form of creation expression doesn't affect the Thread that is created.  You could argue it is an inline `Thread`, but such capitalization and quotation would not come through in a verbal framing of the question.)

Comment: @Roman not really. The page says “*without implementing Runnable or extending Thread*” where the code example *is* extending Thread, so it’s factually wrong and you have to continue to wait for a useful answer on that page…

Answer (score 72):

I believe it refers to the practice of creating an anonymous class extending Thread and calling its start method in the same line of code.

```
(new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    // do stuff
  }
 }).start();
```

As stated elsewhere, this is not an "official" Java term.  But I think it's still good to know how concepts might be referred to differently, if only for the sake of communication.

Answer (score 11):

"inline thread" is not an established term in Java. It was a bad question.

Some people seem to use the term to mean threads defined using anonymous classes, as shown in the other answers. But again, this is not official or even widespread usage, and not something by which you could usefully measure someone's Java knowledge.

Comment: Some people may consider it a reasonable question to assess the candidates ability to interactively clear up botched communications.

Comment: It may be not a established term, but fact is, that I used this key words to find an example in the web and I found a lot of example like the one delivered by danben. So what is "established" exactly???

Answer (score 11):

I am guessing this means creating a thread sorta like...

```
new Thread(
  new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
         ...
      }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 5):

It's really just another name for an anonymous thead.

```
( new Thread() { public void run() { 
// do something 
} } ).start();
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are a bit outdated.

You can use `Thread`s with [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
new Thread(() -> doSomething()).start();
```

it's short, precise and still very readable (i.e. elegant).

Comment: An answer to “what did the interviewer mean, back then” can never get outdated. It is very clear that the interviewer did not mean lambda expressions when they said “inline thread”. On the other hand, the thing, they most probably meant, a form a subclassing `Thread`, was outdated even back then. But that’s not the point.

Comment: @Holger I was arguing, that if an interviewer asked to inline a thread nowadays, a thread with a lambda would be a better answer. Questions on SO are not frozen in time. We always want to keep answers to questions relevant, for people who may find the question in the future. This thread is not just about solving OPs problem, but to help anyone with a similar problem in the future. but as programming languages change, so do the answers to programming questions

Comment: Well, anything is better than an anonymous inner class that can produce an unintended memory leak. That was true a decade ago and even a decade ago before that. But if you dare to tell an interviewer that there’s something better than what they asked for, you could also tell them that “inline thread” isn’t an actual thing.

Comment: @Holger I see that you are unhappy with the usage of the term "inline thread". Maybe I am wrong, but I believe everybody semantically understands what is meant when people say "inline Thread", which is a Thread that is not defined as an outer class, but rather at the point where it is executed, one could say in-place, or "inline". An inner class fits this as much as creating a Thread with a lambda as a parameter. To be perfectly honest, I am not even sure what we are discussing right now..

Comment: You posted an answer to a question which literally asked “*What is "inline thread"?*” because the questioner didn’t know it. The top three answers use “believe”, “seem”, or “guessing” because *they don’t know* for sure. Even one of the Java architects [said “*Guess I would fail this interview*”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000218/#comment125303593_2000218) due to this non-idiomatic term. So no, not “everybody semantically understands what is meant”. If everybody understood, this question wouldn’t exist. So, the other answers aren’t outdated, they addressed the actual question.